# Error in updating Kali-Linux

Tags: linux

### I'm trying to run update or upgrade commands in kali but it gives an error list as below: (I used `sudo` as well, same error happens when I run `autoremove, remove, clean` and `autoclean`)

```
┌──(rootkali)-[/]
└─# apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libcapstone3 libcrypto++6 libdap25 libexo-1-0 libexo-helpers libgdal27 libgeos-3.8.1 libjs-sizzle libllvm10 libmicrohttpd12 libplymouth4 libpython3.8
  libpython3.8-dev libpython3.8-minimal libpython3.8-stdlib libqt5opengl5 libradare2-4.3.1 libsane libwireshark13 libwiretap10 libwsutil11 libxcb-util0
  node-jquery python3-atomicwrites python3-gevent python3-greenlet python3-zope.event python3.8 python3.8-dev python3.8-minimal qt5-gtk2-platformtheme
  ruby-connection-pool ruby-molinillo ruby-net-http-persistent ruby-thor xfce4-mailwatch-plugin xfce4-smartbookmark-plugin xfce4-statusnotifier-plugin
  xfce4-weather-plugin
Use 'apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages have been kept back:
  clang default-mysql-server kali-desktop-core kali-linux-core libcrypt-ssleay-perl libdbd-mariadb-perl libdbi-perl libfcgi-perl libfile-fcntllock-perl
  libhtml-parser-perl liblocale-gettext-perl libnet-dbus-perl libnet-dns-sec-perl libnet-libidn-perl libnet-ssleay-perl libopenconnect5 libsnmp40
  libsocket6-perl libterm-readkey-perl libtext-charwidth-perl libtext-iconv-perl libxml-parser-perl perl perl-base snmp snmpd xfce4 xfce4-settings
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 28 not upgraded.
W: Not using locking for read only lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend
W: Not using locking for read only lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock
W: chown to _apt:root of directory /var/cache/apt/archives/partial failed - SetupAPTPartialDirectory (30: Read-only file system)
W: chmod 0700 of directory /var/cache/apt/archives/partial failed - SetupAPTPartialDirectory (30: Read-only file system)
W: chown to _apt:root of directory /var/lib/apt/lists/auxfiles failed - SetupAPTPartialDirectory (30: Read-only file system)
W: chmod 0755 of directory /var/lib/apt/lists/auxfiles failed - SetupAPTPartialDirectory (30: Read-only file system)
W: Not using locking for read only lock file /var/cache/apt/archives/lock
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To remove old packages in Linux, run:

sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get autoclean && sudo apt-get clean && sudo apt-get autoremove

Restart and then run: sudo apt-get update  *before* running upgrade.

If you do all three in order as I showed, Kali should update.

Posted from Kali 2021.1

Comment: Thank you, it worked just as you said

Comment: That is one of those all purpose command strings I keep in One Note when a Linux system does not want to update.